# Which ongoing requests will be viewed by the reviewer

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Will there be any consequences if I am opening a new Pull request onto the same feature branch (let's call it featureNew) that was already created and contains 1 modified file (done by another user, personA), while mine contains 2 modified files where one of the file is the same as the one that is done by personA?

Meaning to say `featureNew` will have 2 Pull Requests - one from me, and one from personA

- Files from personA : file01
- Files from me : file01, file02

By the way, personA created his PR way earlier than me and it is still Open, and hence I am stepping in to continue modifying changes onto feature branch as he will not be doing it anymore...

Additionally, when my reviewer views the code, will personA changes made to the file01 'overwrites' the contents of my `file01`? Or only the latest PR be displayed to my reviewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter till the pull request is not merged into the branch. Say your pull request was first to get merged then in that case pull request from person A can only be merged if it has no conflicts or can be automatically merged.

Now, say there is a conflict in that case person A will have to pull your code and resolve the conflicts then the pull request will be updated and he can merge his changes.

Comment: do correct me if I am wrong, does that means that on this feature branch, it can have as many pull requests (from different users for example) until the time has come to select one of the PR to be merged?

Comment: You are raising pull requests to merge to this feature branch or You are trying to raise a PR which will merge this feature branch to develop /master etc?

Comment: It will be the latter.. This PR of mine (feature branch) will be merged to develop/master. It is just that I am not sure if a branch can have more than 1 (open) PR?

Comment: Yeah you can have multiple PRs raised by multiple users.

Comment: Okay, noted. Pardon me if I did not make my question or comments clear. Thanks!

Comment: Found out that it will not create a new PR but instead once I pushed my commits, it will be 'on-top' of the PR made by the personA. Comments-section within will state that I have updated the request by adding 1 commit. I think this is the way of how git works to keep things simple, i guess